# Using everyauth with LinkedIn

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api, everyauth

I'm trying to use everyauth to authenticate my app using LinkedIn.
The authentication itself works out of the box, but the object returned by everyauth from LinkedIn (req.user) includes LinkedIn's "basic profile" info only, and not the user's primary email address which is the key information I'm after. I've authorised my app in linkedin  to request r_emailaddress, and I think (looking at the LinkedIn Api docs) that I need to define the SCOPE of the login request to explicitly request the email address.  What I don't know is HOW to do that using everyauth.

I'm keen to continue using everyauth rather than directly the LinkedIn Api since a) everyauth looks very impressive and comprehensive and b) I plan to use additional authentication schemes in future.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyauth uses LinkedIn's oauth API implementation, which is older than the current API implementation oauth2. oauth is still supported but you're probably reading documentation based on oauth2 and it's generally easier to work with.

I would suggest using [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and using the [LinkedIn oauth2 Strategy](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2) as it has worked for me. Good luck!